# Woocommerce Get order items on checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to hook into a 3rd party application when a cart is checked out. Essentially i need to pass information about the order such as the products that are inside the order.

Everything i find points me towards the hook: woocommerce_new_order

When i use that hook i can get some information about the order but not everything.

```
add_action('woocommerce_new_order','order_check',10,1);

function order_check($order_id){
    echo 'Order id is: '.$order_id;
    $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
    print_r($order);

    echo '-----';


    /** CHECK IF order has items */
    $order_item = $order->get_items();
    print_r($order_item);

    exit;
}
```

For instance the above code sample will print the order array but when it call $order->get_items() nothing is returned.

Comment: I am starting to think that the order isn't fully created at the time woocommerce_new_order is called. Even calling get_line_subtotal() returns 0.

Comment: An interesting thing to note... i can access the cart at this point.WC()->cart->cart_contents returns the items in my cart. I guess i will just use that. appears unless anyone can come up with any objections or reasonds not to?

Comment: $order->get_items() will must return the array of order items. you might have missed something else.

Comment: It does if the order is created but at the time the hook in question is called the order is not yet fully created.

Comment: I can verify that everything @AndrewMac is experiencing, I also experience at the moment.  I'm also attempting to call get_items and the array is empty, even though a print_f of the order when looking at the thank you page shows the array populated.  Currently working on / searching for a solution.

Answer (score 5):

At the time `woocommerce_new_order` fires, order items is not yet populated.

Instead, use the hook `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed` and you'll find that all items are then populated.