# Send customer on-hold order notification once order is placed in Woocommerce 3.3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I have this issue. I using Woocommerce 3.3.3 in this moment in my site and noticed one weird issue. After customer placed order, their order is stuck on "On Hold" into Woocommerce orders.

[image: on hold status]

and customer dont get any order confirmation mail. When go to order and move status on order from "On Hold" to "Processing" customer is getting Order Confirmation mail, that should be automatically. Searched, and found this "[fix](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/16617)":

```
add_filter( ‘woocommerce_defer_transactional_emails’, ‘__return_false’ );
```

to be placed into functions.php, but seems that dont changed nothing. Anyone with similar issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```
add_action('woocommerce_new_order', 'new_order_on_hold_notification', 30, 1 );
function new_order_on_hold_notification( $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // Only for on hold new orders
    if( ! $order->has_status('on-hold') )
        return; // Exit

    // Send Customer On-Hold Order notification
    WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_Customer_On_Hold_Order']->trigger( $order_id );
}
```

To change "on-hold" paid orders to "processing" use that:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_woocommerce_auto_prrocessing_paid_order', 10, 1 );
function custom_woocommerce_auto_prrocessing_paid_order( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! $order_id )
       return;

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // No updated status for orders delivered with Bank wire, Cash on delivery and Cheque payment methods.
    if ( in_array( $order->get_payment_method(), array( 'bacs', 'cod', 'cheque', '' ) ) ) {
        return;
    } 
    // "Processing" updated status for paid Orders with all others payment methods
    else {
        if( $order->has_status('on-hold') )
            $order->update_status( 'processing' );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

Comment: Hi, inserted your code into functions.php from active theme, and tryed again to place order. After placing order, order still stuck on "On Hold" . See image: https://i.imgur.com/9wyP9GF.png?1

Also i see in your code you Send On-Hold Mail, but i think that must be Processing Order Or not? On hold mail also is enabled from Woo Backend. https://i.imgur.com/6fMs6cM.png?1

Comment: @JoeKooker **Not for Orders placed from gateways as "cheque", "cash on delivery" or "bank wire" that should be set manually from "on hold" to "processing" (or "completed").** My code just send an email notification to the customer when an order has been placed with an "on-hold" status *(what you asked in your question)* … So what do you want *(as it's not clear in your question),* You want to change paid orders only from on-hold to processing?

Comment: Yes sorry maybe my title was not clear. I want . Yes i want when user place order to get new order confirmation mail. Thats all. Currently for on-hold dont get any mail.

Comment: @JoeKooker My code does send an on-hold notification for placed on-hold orders, but doesn't change the order status (as explained in my other comment). You can't change order status only for paid orders on others gateways that the one I have mention it: If you want that you should ask a **new question** and I will answer it.

Comment: Can after send on-hold mail to send mail for processing too?

Comment: Not for Orders placed from gateways as "cheque", "cash on delivery" or "bank wire" that should be set manually from "on hold" to "processing" (or "completed"). What is the gateway  for that on-hold orders that you have? **Processing status is ONLY for paid orders** that are processed by the shop manager (like checking shipping or something else)…

Comment: Paypal and Stripe.

Comment: Still after your latest mod, placed orders via check, COD still stuck on "on hold " after being placed..

Comment: Cheque and COD (or BACS) are not handled as they need to be processed manually, aas I have mentioned. When customer has @JoeKooker paid, the shop manager change manually the order status to "processing" or "completed"… **Do you understand?** as I have said before **"Processing" or "Completed"  status is ONLY for paid orders**

Comment: OK so now when someone place order via Paypal for ex. will get confirmation mail ?

Comment: Yes if the notifications for processing / completed are enabled the customer will receive a notification and for admin the "new order" notification need to be enabled.

Comment: isn't the status key `wc-on-hold` instead of just `on-hold`?

Comment: @SsouLlesS When using the `WC_Order` methods `get_status()`, `set_status()` or `has_status()` you will not need to use `wc-` before the order status slug.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec please check the last answer I added, which really provides a real-world usage example.

Comment: @SsouLlesS Sorry but I don't agree… When the hook woocommerce_new_order is triggered, the order is already created and saved to the database with all details, just after the payment gateway process.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec sorry but you're wrong, there's many issues related to this, check this question Im not the only one who noticed this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35563364/woocommerce-get-order-items-on-checkout

Comment: @SsouLlesS I will check as this was working fine when I wrote the answer… If it's the case I will update my answer.

Comment: @SsouLlesS Sorry, but yes it is, even if you have added an answer, as mine is the accepted one. And this fact is due to woocommerce changes since 2018.

Answer (score 0):

Just to point out:

The solution @LoicTheAztec mentioned works:

```
add_action('woocommerce_new_order', 'new_order_on_hold_notification', 30, 1 );
function new_order_on_hold_notification( $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // Only for on hold new orders
    if( ! $order->has_status('on-hold') )
        return; // Exit

    // Send Customer On-Hold Order notification
    WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_Customer_On_Hold_Order']->trigger( $order_id );
}
```

However there's an issue with this solution, at the time `woocommerce_new_order`hook is called the order hasn't been fully created yet, so as result in the email notification the order items are not displayed. Use the following hook instead:

```
    add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'new_order_on_hold_notification');   
    function new_order_on_hold_notification( $order_id ) {
                    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

                    // Only for on hold new orders
                    if( ! $order->has_status('on-hold') )
                        return; // Exit

                    // Send Customer On-Hold Order notification
                    WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_Customer_On_Hold_Order']->trigger( $order_id );
     }
```

At the time `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed` is called the order items are already available for your email.